# Git Hook PHP Script: No Output

Tags: java, php, git

I have this Script `php-pull-script.php`written:

```
<?php
  $output1 = shell_exec('git pull');
  $output2 = shell_exec('pkill java');
  $output3 = shell_exec('mvn package');
  $output4 = shell_exec('java -jar ./target/compute-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar');

  echo "<pre>$output1</pre>";
  echo "<pre>$output2</pre>";
  echo "<pre>$output3</pre>";
  echo "<pre>$output4</pre>";
?>
```

When executing in shell, I am not seeing any output in order to verify that it is running. I am not sure at all it is working. Is there a better way to do this automation script?

Comment: Those commands may have no output? Btw why are you using `<pre>` on **cmd**?

Comment: Maybe a CRONJOB on Linux level? And if one of these calls are `interactive` it wont work!

Comment: yes pre is maybe the first thing to get rid of here. :)

Comment: And just for testing try `shell_exec('git --version')` and then see  the output.

Comment: How to send of the java command with `shell_exec` and leave it running in background (Is `&` possible with shell exec)?

Comment: @Stephan Kristyn Yes it is possible but you have also redirect all output to NULL, if not php wait for STDIN/STDERR to close.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be in the correct working directory. You may need to [set that manually](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) to make the commands run. Otherwise, those commands look right. Though you really should just have this set up as a shell script. PHP's not a good language for this sort of thing, and if you are calling this from a REST endpoint there are far better solutions like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/).

Answer (score 0):

How to send of the java command with shell_exec and leave it running in background (Is & possible with shell exec)?

test.php

```
 <?php
 shell_exec('test.sh');
```

test.sh

```
 echo "Do something"
 /bin/sh -c 'sleep 10' >> /dev/null 2>&1 &

 exit 0
```

- `/dev/null` can be also a path to an logfile
- All pathes here and in phpscript should be absolute, like: /path/tomy/test.sh

Here the test.php doesnt wait 10 seconds for the subcall.

Hope that helps a little ;)

Comment: Thanks, thats what I needed!

Comment: @Stephan Kristyn Then gimmi the check;)

Comment: StackOverflow requires us to wait for a couple of minutes for the check.

Comment: Interestingly everything works in my new bash script, except for this command: `/usr/bin/java -jar /home/user/folder/target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. Getting a `./rebuild-project.sh: line 6: 25288 Terminated`

Comment: Putting in Backticks and executing with echo helped for more complex commands.

Comment: @Stephan Kristyn    `25288 Terminated` means the sub-process that was runnig the java was killed, run the script directly and look for errors.

Comment: @Stephan Kristyn If you are using often bash i thing you should read about the topic. Like this: exit-status of shell procs, and how to react. And many more ...